# How to install C# App from one computer to another

Tags: c#, usb-flash-drive

My scenario is that I have two computers A and B.  Computer A has an installed C# windows forms application on it.  Pretending that I dont have the source code to publish onto B, is it possible to move the app from A to B?  If so, what files do I need in order to copy it over?

Comment: That is a pretty open ended question : how long is a piece of string, how are we supposed to know what files your application needs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that your question doesn't appear to be programming related and therefore it probably isn't on topic for this site. Please review the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Even if you knew where the binaries are, you may have stability issues if the installation process modifies things like registry entries, GAC assemblies, etc.

Having said that, you should be able to find the location of the exe and associated dlls by searching windows for the the exe name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the C# application requires files found in the local appdata directory, if so you'll need to copy them.

It can be difficult when apps require a certain DLL then you'll need to find the dependencies for the application and install them on Computer B.

After you've done that you can copy all the files that are in the programs directory and you MIGHT be good to go.

Best thing to do is make sure you have the installer handy :)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I just wish that publishing the program is just one file without all this extra dependency stuff.  It would make distributing it so much easier.

Comment: Thats what installers are for

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer without knowing the application.

Sometimes it's enough to just copy the files over. However, if the app relies on registry entries, databases or some other prerequisites copying files is not enough.